# Error when using findstr on file directory

Tags: batch-file, findstr

So I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of findstr since it's come up a few times on other batch script questions I've had. I'm trying to have it look for a word (in this case 'webview') through multiple files in a directory, ideally it would pull the line it was found as well as the file name. However, the program gets stuck in this sort of infinite loop with it and I have to force an exit. Any help on if its being caused by the findstr or what is causing it would be amazing as I've been staring at it for several hours now. My current code is below:

```
ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

ECHO Please input the path to the app directory you'd like scanned
SET /p directorypath=
CD %directorypath%

ECHO Scanning files for Webview
(
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /S /M "webview" *.json') DO (
    SET "line=%%a"
    SET "line=!line:*webview=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<" %%b in (!line!) DO ECHO %%b
)) > WebviewScanResults.txt

:eof
```

UPDATE: Code updated and functional for use as a reference. I pretty much just run the above code a couple of time with different file types replacing *.json and it works fine.

Comment: The /M option outputs only filenames containing the search key.

Comment: You can take a look at this batch file [Local_Search_Engine.bat](https://pastebin.com/ADdjPEfH)

Comment: I believe there is no infinite loop, but `findstr` is awaiting data at the console as you did not specify any file(s) to search nor you did not redirect or pipe any data in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an untested try, too late for me:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

ECHO Please input the path to the app directory you'd like scanned
SET /p directorypath=
PushD "%directorypath%"

ECHO Scanning files for Webview
(
FOR /F "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /S "webview" *.html') DO (
    SET "line=%%b"
    SET "line=!line:*webview=!"
    FOR /F "delims=<>" %%b in ("!line!") DO ECHO %%a:%%b
)) > WebviewScanResults.txt
```

Comment: I'm trying to search all the files in the folder as explained above, is there a better thing to use for this?

Comment: What file type do you want to search through?

Comment: I'm trying to look through JSON files, but ideally it would be able to handle many different types of files inside this directory.

Comment: findstr won't handle binary files. You should start small - change the *.html to *.json then. Findstr with wildcards in the file will put the file name in front of each matched line seperated by a colon.

Comment: Batch isn't the best choices dealing with files containing lots of chars which need special treatment to escape. PowerShell understands xml,json,html for example.